# Magento: overriding Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4

Tags: php, magento

I spent almost two days on searching the web about this topic, but i don't know why my class doesn't override Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4 (core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php).

My class is

```
class Company_Module_Model_Override_CatalogSearch_Resource_Helper_Mysql4 extends
    Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4
{
}
```

the file is located in 
local/Company/Module/Model/Override/CatalogSearch/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php

My config file is:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalogsearch_resource_helper>
            <rewrite>
                    <mysql4>Company_Module_Model_Override_CatalogSearch_Resource_Helper_Mysql4</mysql4>
                </rewrite>
            </catalogsearch_resource_helper>
    </models>
</global>
```

The module override other modules without problems, so I cannot figure out how to solve... Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: Ok, i solved.. the right way to extend this class is:
<global>
 <models>
  <catalogsearch_resource>
   <rewrite> 
    <helper_mysql4>Company_Module_Model_Override_CatalogSearch_Resource_Helper_Mysql4</helper_mysql4>
   </rewrite>
  </catalogsearch_resource>
 </models>
</global>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting here the solution I came up with.
The right override declaration in the config.xml file should be as following:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalogsearch_resource>
            <rewrite>
                  <helper_mysql4>Company_Module_Model_Override_CatalogSearch_Resource_Helper_Mysql4</helpr_mysql4>
            </rewrite>
        </catalogsearch_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enzo, instead of doing all this stuff just copy Mysql.php from core directory 
app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Resource\Helper and paste it in your local directory 
app\code\local\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Resource\Helper and modify your code accordingly

Comment: Thank you Ram, I know this trick, but i don't want to do this way because my target is to have a module not depending on Mage files.
Anyway, i solved the problem... it was quite simple, once I know :)

Comment: Don't copy core files to `local` codepool unless they are abstract classes that are never instantiated. I don't think this is the case

Comment: @Marius, I agree with you.